# Server times out with two requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, webforms

I have an odd problem.

In asp.net (C#) I have a web form with a text field and a button.

The text field has autopostback enabled with a text_changed event.
The button has a click even also.

If the text changes in the field and the user clicks the button without losing the focus on the text field first, the two events seem to "clash" on the server and the request takes a good 2-3 minutes to return nothing.

If the text changes in the field and the field loses focus before the button is clicked, the events are fired separately and everything is OK.

I need to be able to allow the users to go straight to clicking the button when they've changed the text.

Has anyone else seen this problem, and if so how do you get around it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the textbox event?

Comment: we needz code plz. Also i think it's pretty impossible for the server to timout based on some javascript event. There is something wrong server-side too.

Comment: The text box event does some math and updates figures on the page. Not all users need to see the change, some other would want to change the result before clicking the button.

Comment: What your button do ?Is your button and textbox event both updating same table?? Check if your query is locking table .         **http://aartemiou.blogspot.in/2011/08/updating-sql-server-tables-without.html**

Comment: the button adds a record to a table, the text changed event does nothing more than update some text on the page for visual confirmation of a result before submitting. So there's no locking of tables I think.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use jquery.

```
better to Use Keyup Or Keydown of jquery event instead of textchanged event. 
and false the autopost property of textbox.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but try this:

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET") == Button2.UniqueID)
        return;
    Debug.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text);
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Text");
}
```

Notice the check for the EventTarget. When I tested this it seemed that even though when you click the button (without tabbing) the click event gets ignored and only the text changed event fires. Adding the extra check in the text changed event seems to solve this. This is a slight flaw though, sometimes (not all the time) the text changed event gets called twice, you might have to handle this in your code.